# mySql Select with Upper/Lower

Tags: mysql, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to write a select from two tables where fields containing strings are UpperCase in only one table but the query and the subquery don't seem to work togheter:

This works:

```
SELECT City, Country
FROM Cities INNER JOIN Countries USING(IdCountry)
WHERE LOWER(Cities.City) IN
(LOWER('NEW YORK'), LOWER('PARIS'), LOWER('LONDON'))
```

This also works:

```
SELECT LOWER(location) FROM locations
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT City, Country
FROM Cities INNER JOIN Countries USING(IdCountry)
WHERE LOWER(Cities.City) IN
(SELECT LOWER(location) FROM locations)
```

I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: What collation are you using on these columns (i.e. does case even matter for columns in question)?  Why do you not have your data formatted properly at rest?  Running your field values through a function call such as `LOWER()` is going to prevent you from using any indexes on these fields, leading to sub-optimal queries.

Comment: Thought about using a case-insensitive collation?

Comment: this should work, i tried in my scenerio it works, what error do you get

Comment: @Mike Brant: I'm just trying to extract data from csv files (imported) to put them in my database. @  juergen d: What are you suggesting? @ A.B: No Rows

Comment: do you have spaces or any other mis match between the table locations?

Comment: @genespos please create a sqlfiddle

Comment: @A.B. you identified what was wrong: I realize that there were spaces while preparing an sqlfiddle test. Thanks everybody